# Unexpected Error in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to create a query to order a list of puppies based on weight, however it is not working and I receive the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity exp
ected - got '<database_setup.Puppy object at 0x02B7E590>'
```

Other variables from the same class were ordered appropriately without error, my code looks as follows

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from database_setup import *
#from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from random import randint
import datetime
import random


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///puppies.db')

Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()


#Format for query 
#session.query(*table*)self.filter_by(*criteria*)

# 1. Query all of the puppies and return the results in ascending alphabetical order

#so we call a query on the Shelter table where we order by name
SheltersAlphabetically = session.query(Shelter).order_by(Shelter.name.desc())

for Shelter in SheltersAlphabetically:
    print Shelter.name

print '\n'
# 2. Query all of the puppies that are less than 6 months old organized by the youngest first
today = datetime.date.today()


PuppiesByAge = session.query(Puppy).filter(Puppy.dateOfBirth > '2014-12-03').order_by(Puppy.dateOfBirth)

for Puppy in PuppiesByAge:
    print Puppy.dateOfBirth

print '\n'

# 3. Query all puppies by ascending weight

PuppiesByWeight = session.query(Puppy).order_by(Puppy.weight)

for Puppy in PuppiesByWeight:
    print Puppy.weight
```

my original set up file looks as follows

```
import os 
import sys #provides key functions and variables

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String #good for mapper ode

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base #used for config and class code

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship #for foreign key relationships n mampper

from sqlalchemy import create_engine  # for config code

Base = declarative_base() # an instance of class we jsut improted,
                          #lets sql alchemy know our classes are special 
                          #sql alchemy classes, correspond to tables in databae

class Shelter (Base):
    __tablename__ =  'shelter'
    name = Column ( String(200), nullable = False)
    id = Column (Integer, primary_key = True)
    address = Column ( String(200), nullable = True)
    city = Column ( String(100), nullable = True)
    state = Column ( String(100), nullable = True)
    zipCode = Column ( String(100), nullable = True)
    website = Column ( String(200), nullable = True)

class Puppy (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'puppy'
    name = Column ( String(80), nullable = False)
    id = Column (Integer, primary_key = True)
    dateOfBirth = Column ( Integer, nullable = True)
    breed = Column ( String(100), nullable = True)
    gender = Column ( String(100), nullable = True)
    picture = Column ( String(300), nullable = True)
    weight = Column ( Integer, nullable = True)
    shelter_id = Column ( Integer, ForeignKey('shelter.id'))
    shelter = relationship(Shelter)

#database creation and class integration
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///puppies.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

What can I do to avoid this error and perform the query to order the weight?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898551/python-sqlalchemy-got-invalidrequesterror-after-change-class-location). Be careful, don't do `from database_setup import *`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the local variable name `Puppy` - that name is already taken for the  `Puppy` class that you import.

I suggest you use `puppy` (all lower case) for variables in your code that represent a puppy.

Local variables in Python should by convention use lower case: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables